# HAProxy backend limit session's sum is wrong

Tags: haproxy

My Configuration is same as below.

```
frontend stats
    bind *:8181
    maxconn 10
    mode http
    stats enable
    stats refresh 10s
    stats auth admin:password
    stats uri  /haproxy?stats

frontend rserve_frontend
    bind *:8400
    mode tcp
    maxconn 3000
    option tcplog
    timeout client  1m
    default_backend rserve_backend

backend rserve_backend
    mode tcp
    option tcplog
    option log-health-checks
    option redispatch
    log global
    balance roundrobin
    timeout connect 10s
    timeout server 1m
    server server01 192.168.201.19:8400 check maxconn 1500
    server server02v 192.168.200.17:8400 check maxconn 1500
```

But I don't know why the backend maxconnection is displaying 300.

Is it kind of bug? or my wrong configuration?
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation for the `fullconn` setting covers this a bit.

> Since it's hard to get this value right, haproxy automatically sets it to
> 10% of the sum of the maxconns of all frontends that may branch to this
> backend (based on "use_backend" and "default_backend" rules). That way it's
> safe to leave it unset. However, "use_backend" involving dynamic names are
> not counted since there is no way to know if they could match or not.

https://www.haproxy.com/documentation/hapee/latest/onepage/#4.2-fullconn